# Spring - Autowired is null - Test - UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'm trying to test my application, I've been trying to solve it for 3 days and I looked for stackoverflow and I still couldn't solve it.
My problem is that Autowired is always null, and even though I import everything suggested as

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest
public class ESGControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private ESGController esgController ;
    @Test
    public void deveRetornarSucesso_QuandoBuscarLatLong(){
        System.out.println(this.esgController);
    }

}
```

or

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration
public class ESGControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private ESGController esgController ;
    @Test
    public void deveRetornarSucesso_QuandoBuscarLatLong(){
        System.out.println(this.esgController);
    }

}
```

is always null and gives this error

[image]

EDIT:
ESGController

```
package br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.controller;

import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.dto.CargaDTO;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.dto.CargaFilter;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.entity.AreaEmbargada;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.entity.Carga;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.entity.ConfiguracaoCarga;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.exception.CargaException;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.inteface.HereReverseGeocode;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.inteface.HereSearch;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.service.CargaService;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.service.ConfiguracaoCargaService;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.service.IbamaService;
import br.com.kmm.esgeniusapi.service.ReverseGeocodeService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/api/")
@RolesAllowed("VIEW")
@Component
public class ESGController {

    @Autowired
    ReverseGeocodeService reverseGeocodeService;

    @Autowired
    IbamaService ibamaService;

    @Autowired
    CargaService cargaService;

    @Autowired
    ConfiguracaoCargaService configuracaoCargaService;

    @GetMapping(path = "reverse-geocode")
    public HereReverseGeocode getRoute(@RequestParam final String location) {
        Double lat = Double.parseDouble(location.split(",")[0]);
        Double lon = Double.parseDouble(location.split(",")[1]);
        return this.reverseGeocodeService.getReverseGeocoding(lat, lon);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "search")
    public List<HereSearch> search(@RequestParam(name = "q") final String query) {
        return this.reverseGeocodeService.search(query);
    }
     ....{
    //MORE FUNCTIONS
     }
}
```

I edited and put the ESGController as code for more information.

Comment: Can you post the code for ESGController?

Comment: I edited and put the ESGController as code for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Is ESGController decorated with @Controller or equivalent so that a bean of that class actually exist in the context?

Is the test class in the same package hierarchy as the rest of the application?

> @SpringBootTest by default starts searching in the current package of
> the test class and then searches upwards through the package
> structure, looking for a class annotated with @SpringBootConfiguration
> from which it then reads the configuration to create an application
> context.

Comment: I put the @Component but it still gave the same error.

Comment: How do I know if the package is in the same hierarchy as the application?

Comment: Ah it's a controller, i. that case @Component is redundant. Basically the package name should be the same for the class under test and test class.

Comment: I put it in the same package and now it's stating that no tests were found

Comment: https://prnt.sc/BUkluXVT1k1_

Comment: What more does that stacktrace say? It looks like you are using the junit4 vintage engine, don't you want to use the junit5 engine? Check that you are importing the test annotations from the right package. To use junit5 import from ‘import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;‘

Comment: I tried with this import, still the same error

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. The only thing I can recommend now is to check https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ and try to figure out what part is missing in your test.